# App crashes - Cannot figure out why

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, crash

My app tends to crash when it launches the first time, but when I launch it again. The app is fine.

It crashes when I press a button, the button plays a sound and allows the user to change the pitch and BPM of the song playing.

Here is the crash report from the log

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 1842.
2012-07-31 19:40:33.437 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.447 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.477 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.483 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.493 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.498 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.508 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:33.515 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-31 19:40:42.449 DubstepDJ[1842:16a03] Starting
```

This is the code where it crashes

```
- (OSStatus) readFloatsConsecutive:(SInt64)numFrames intoArray:(float**)audio
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;

    if (!mExtAFRef) return -1;

    int kSegmentSize = (int)(numFrames * mExtAFNumChannels * mExtAFRateRatio + .5);
    if (mExtAFRateRatio < 1.) kSegmentSize = (int)(numFrames * mExtAFNumChannels /
        mExtAFRateRatio + .5);

    AudioBufferList bufList;
    UInt32 numPackets = numFrames; // Frames to read
    UInt32 samples = numPackets * mExtAFNumChannels;
    UInt32 loadedPackets = numPackets;

    short *data = (short*)malloc(kSegmentSize*sizeof(short));
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"data is nil");
        goto error;
    }

    bufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = mExtAFNumChannels;
    bufList.mBuffers[0].mData = data; // data is a pointer (short*) to our sample buffer
    bufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = samples * sizeof(short);

    // Crash occurs on this line:
    **err = ExtAudioFileRead(mExtAFRef, &loadedPackets, &bufList);**
    if (err) goto error;

    if (audio) {
        for (long c = 0; c < mExtAFNumChannels; c++) {
            if (!audio[c]) continue;
            for (long v = 0; v < numFrames; v++) {
                if (v < loadedPackets) audio[c][v] = (float)data[v*mExtAFNumChannels+c] / 32768.f;
                else audio[c][v] = 0.f;
            }
        }
    }

error:
    free(data);
    if (err != noErr) return err;
    if (loadedPackets < numFrames) mExtAFReachedEOF = YES;
    return loadedPackets;
}
```

I've made the part bold on the line Xcode says 'exc_bad_access'

Thanks

Comment: Tags are not required in the title of your question.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I edited it again, since the previous edit seems to have damaged the code block.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with framework you're trying to use. And in the case it is built-in frameworks as I see, I think there is something wrong with your xCode. Try reinstalling it.